# Change calculator (printing final value)

Tags: c

I'm writing a code that takes a value from 1 to 100 and converts it to change (i.e. 16 cents is 1 dime, 1 nickel, and 1 cent). My problem is when I'm printing the change values.

The punctuation has to be correct so for 10 cents, it has to be "1 dime." and not "1 dime,".

Other than using a ton of if statements, is there a more efficient way to take into account all the possibilities of having quarters, but no nickels/dimes/cents, having quarters and nickels, but no nickels/cents, etc. and print the write punctuation/combination of change outputs?

Thank you!!!

```
// quarters
    if (quarters== 1 && dimes==0 && nickels==0 && cents == 0)
        printf("%d quarter.", quarters);
    else if (quarters>= 1 && dimes==0 && nickels==0 && cents == 0)
        printf("%d quarters.", quarters);
    // include other combinations
    else if (quarters==1)
        printf("%d quarter, ", quarters);
    else if (quarters>=1)
        printf("%d quarters, ", quarters);
```

Comment: Is this the exercise for the CS50 course?  If so, please add the CS50 tag.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [Ask] and [About] pages soon, and the material on how to produce an MCVE ([MCVE]) now.  If you search on SO using '`[cs50] dime`', you will find quite a lot of relevant material; similar queries may show more.  You've not shown your variable declarations. You can probably do things more efficiently by only generating the stop (`.`) when you know you're done, and by prepending a comma-space when you've already printed something.  That way, you can treat each coin separately.

Comment: Have you covered arrays at all?  Have you covered structures at all?  The problem cries out for the use of an array of structures, but if you've not covered those yet, it isn't fair to do more than hint that "it will be easier when you know more".

Answer (score 1):

About comma and period:

You will have a comma -after the quarter- if their is dime, nickel or cent.
So instead of testing if `dime` is not `0`, `nickel` is not `0`, `cent` is not `0`, you can sum these values and test if it's `0` or not.

About `'s'`, you just have to know if their `1` coin or more.

Giving that, you can make a function that will format only one coin type. This function should be responsible of choosing to add an 's' or not, and choose between comma and period. Each choice can be made whit one `if/else` test, so you can have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*
  what: name of coin
  quantity: number of coin
  rest: coins that must be displayed after
*/
void print_coin(const char *what, int quantity, int rest)
{
    /* is there something to display*/
    if (0 == quantity)
        { return; }
    /* One coin*/    
    else if (1 == quantity)
        { printf("1 %s", what) ;}
    /* several coins, add an 's' */
    else
       { printf("%d %ss", quantity, what) ;}

    /* choose between comma and period */
    if (rest > 0)
        { printf(", ");}
    else 
        { printf(".\n");}
}

/* print all coins function */
void print_coins(int quarter, int dime, int nickel)
{
    /* print each coins, one after the other */

    print_coin("quarter", quarter, dime + nickel);
    print_coin("dime", dime, nickel);
    print_coin("nickel", nickel, 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    /* examples */
    print_coins(1, 2, 3);
    print_coins(1, 0, 1);
    print_coins(1, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```